# Sync between an iPhone and iPad without Internet connection

Tags: ios, data-synchronization

Is it possible to sync between an iPhone and an iPad directly when there is no Internet connection (like a remote location or an outage at the Internet provider)?

Using a direct wireless connection between just the iPhone and the iPad (without using a PC or a WiFi router)

I need to sync all data (contacts, calendar, reminders, photos, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot sync an iPhone with an iPad or vice versa without using some cloud service like iCloud or a computer in between.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? For automatic downloads of recent purchases, you don't need a connected PC, just a working internet connection on the iPhone/iPad.

Comment: As I said in my question I want to sync without an Internet connection (like on remote places or a network outage)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting, to magically sync without any wired nor wireless connection?

Comment: I want to sync using wireless connection between the devices (but no connection to the Internet)

Comment: Yes, as I said, if your computer and iPhone/iPad are connected to the same local network, you can sync by activating the wi-fi sync. See the link in my edit.

Comment: I thought Wi-Fi sync only worked between an iOS device and the PC iTunes. Do you have any reference to the statement that Wi-Fi sync works directly between iOS devices?

Comment: Now I get the confusion, you should rephrase your question because it is easy to interpret it as if you want to sync an iPhone and an iPad with a computer.